# Does an Australian permanent resident need a visa to visit the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, australian-residents

Do you need a visa for Britain if holding Australian PR  with a  protection visa 
Have been on hold on the Passport office for 2 hrs and also rang the embassy (on Hold)

Comment: Try this UK government web site: [https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa)

Comment: What is your nationality, as visa rules are based on that and not on residency?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you do need a visa for the UK.

> Do you need a visa for Britain if holding Australian PR

Australian PR does not grant visitor visa exemptions for the UK if you require a visa otherwise.

<sub>*If the OP had visa free access to the UK depending upon their nationality, there was no need for this question. This answer assumes that OP has a passport that requires advance visa arrangements for the UK.</sub>

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily correct, it really depends on OP's nationality.

Comment: Doesn't this answer say the same thing? If *(because of their nationality)* they require a visa otherwise, then they still do even with Australian PR.

Comment: Yes, that's fine, however the first line says 'Yes, you do need a visa for the UK.', but it really should be 'Yes, you might need a visa for the UK'. Because there's a chance that the OP has a nationality which does not need a visa for the UK.